SQL/Laravel: Получение родителей в древовидной структуре данных
Всем привет) Использую Laravel, MariaDB.
К примеру есть у нас такая таблица, допустим categories.



id
name
_lft
_rgt
parent_id
path
is_folder




1373
Окна
1
10
NULL
1373
1


1374
Стеклопакет
2
7
1373
1373.1374
1


1375
Фурнитура
8
9
1373
1373.1375
1


1376
Установка
3
4
1374
1373.1374.1376
0


1377
Регулировка
5
6
1374
1373.1374.1377
0



Модель Categories использует трейт Kalnoy\Nestedset\NodeTrait.
В коде ниже билдер запроса уже содержит базовые фильтры (например по name)
if (!empty($filters['recursiveSearch']) && CommonService::parseBoolean($filters['recursiveSearch']) === true) {
    /** @var QueryBuilder $query */
}

Нужно чтобы при передаче параметра recursiveSearch выводились не только подходящие под фильтр значения, но и все их родители.
Например: по фильтру name=регулир получим строку Регулировка. при recursiveSearch также нужно получить Окна и Стеклопакет.
Изначально я думал сделать просто with('ancestors'), но результат попадает в релейшны, а должен в основной запрос.
Потом я сделал доп запрос, получил результат первой выборки, получил pluck('ancestors') и уже их айдишники подставил в результирующий запрос. Это сработало, но если в первоначальной выборке будет к примеру 1000 записей и у каждой по 3 родителя то в итоге будет where на 3000 айди.

Также в запросе может быть фильтр parentId. Если parentId=null&name=регулир&recursiveSearch=true то должно вернуть Окна
Прошу помощи :)

вы пробовали whereHas ?
Categories::whereHas('ancestor', function($q){
$q->whereLike('name', '%регулир%');
})
